# Component Refresh Not Happening

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning

I have a component that is opened with an action.  On the account, I have a button that opens the component.  When I do this, I can see the DoInit firing.  However, if I navigate back to that account record and click the button, the DoInit is not firing.  If I refresh the account page first and click the button, it fires.

Is this a browser issue?   I have been working on another issue (that is posted here yesterday) where my page is not refreshing with data committed when I navigate back to my first component. I'm wondering if that problem is related.

Any input would be greatly appreciated!

Thanks!

Fred

Comment: Is it a lightning quick action or a custom lightning component that has a button on it. Can you edit your question and more details along with code if needed?

Comment: By action do you mean quick action? is it standard or you using modal or overlayLibrary for it?

Comment: Thanks for responding!  I am using a custom Detail Page button with the following:  /lightning/n/Group_Structures_List?//Aid={! Account.Id }&//Tid=123456789